# Cannot View Java Website in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, java, java-applet

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit. Java is installed already and "View Java contents in web browser" is enabled in "Configure Java". Security settings in IE11 are at minimum level, but still when I visit website with Java applet it tells me to go to java.com and install java.

I downloaded latest version from java.com (offline installer) but it's not getting installed on the PC. It's saying "This app cannot run on this PC".

Comment: Did you already try to [disable ActiveX Filtering in Internet Explorer](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/activex-filtering-in-internet-explorer-9-disables-java-and-flash/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. 64bit Windows 10 came with 64bit java but I guess IE is 32bit. Installing 32bit java solved the issue.